# spark-avro fails to parse custom avro file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am attempting to use spark-avro_2.10-0.1 with Spark 1.2.0 to parse a custom avro file compressed with snappy.

I am starting spark as follows:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 16g --driver-cores 8 --executor-memory 32g --executor-cores 16 --jars libs/spark-avro_2.10-0.1.jar,libs/spark-csv-assembly-0.1.1.jar
```

I am able to run the sample code from spark-avro but when I attempt to read a custom avro I get java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.mapred.Pair cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record even for simple operations like count.

I have verified the avro file is good by running:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.3.jar getschema part-00011.avro
```

and

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.3.jar tojson part-00011.avro
```

which is giving me what I expect.

Here is detailed run where I am experiencing the error:

```
    Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
15/02/13 08:25:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Spark context available as sc.

scala> // example code, works fine

scala> 

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

scala> val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@479d0c7

scala> import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

scala> val episodes = sqlContext.avroFile("../ptest/episodes.avro")
episodes: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = 
SchemaRDD[0] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:108
== Query Plan ==
== Physical Plan ==
PhysicalRDD [title#0,air_date#1,doctor#2], MappedRDD[2] at map at AvroRelation.scala:64

scala> import sqlContext._
import sqlContext._

scala> episodes.select('title).collect()
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([The Eleventh Hour], [The Doctor's Wife], [Horror of Fang Rock], [An Unearthly Child], [The Mysterious Planet], [Rose], [The Power of the Daleks], [Castrolava])

scala> 

scala> // avro file that does not work

scala> val events = sqlContext.avroFile("../ptest/part-00011.avro")
events: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = 
SchemaRDD[6] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:108
== Query Plan ==
== Physical Plan ==
PhysicalRDD [key#3,value#4], MappedRDD[8] at map at AvroRelation.scala:64

scala> events.count
[Stage 1:>                                                                                                            (0 + 0) / 2]15/02/13 08:25:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.mapred.Pair cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroRelation$$createConverter$5.apply(AvroRelation.scala:132)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$1.apply(AvroRelation.scala:64)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$1.apply(AvroRelation.scala:64)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Aggregate$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Aggregate.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Aggregate$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Aggregate.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any thoughts on next steps to troubleshoot or other work arounds would be appreciated.

One item to note is the schema contains what look like nested records, like this:

```
    {
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Pair",
  "namespace" : "org.apache.avro.mapred",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "key",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : ""
  }, {
    "name" : "value",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Event",
      "namespace" : "com.dummy.avro",
      "fields" : [
      { ... rest of file omitted
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution or workaround for this exception?

Comment: Hey, Were you able to make it work?

Comment: I'm having this exact problem.  Things were working fine, and one day it just stopped working and gave this error.  Similarly nested avro structure.